# Getting Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-hooks, expo

I am getting this error twice every time I run this. I did my search and tried to cancel the subscription of `onAuthStateChanged()` to `useEffect()` in the cleanup function, but still got the same error. Also, The `uploadAndCreate()` function is working perfectly fine but `createPlan()` is being called even before `createPlan()` finishes because of which I am getting `undefined` for `fileUrl`.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
    Image,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    TextInput,
    TouchableOpacity,
    View,
} from "react-native";
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/storage";
import { Link, Redirect } from "react-router-native";
import { getDocumentAsync } from "expo-document-picker";
import plus from "../../assets/plus.png";
import cross from "../../assets/cross.png";

const NewPlan = (props) => {
    const [planName, setPlanName] = useState();
    const [categoryName, setCategoryName] = useState();
    const [isPlanCreated, setIsPlanCreated] = useState(false);
    const [currUserId, setCurrUserId] = useState();
    const [uploadProgress, setUploadProgress] = useState(0);
    const [blob, setBlob] = useState({});
    const [isPlanNameValid, setIsPlanNameValid] = useState(true);
    const [ref, setRef] = useState();
    const [fileUrl, setFileUrl] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        let mounted = true;

        if (mounted) {
            firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
                if (user) {
                    setCurrUserId(user.uid);
                }
            });
        }

        return () => {
            mounted = false;
        };
    }, []);

    const validate = () => {
        if (planName) {
            setIsPlanNameValid(true);
            uploadAndCreate();
        } else {
            setIsPlanNameValid(false);
        }
    };

    const uploadAndCreate = async () => {
        if (Object.keys(blob).length !== 0) {
            let task = ref.put(blob);

            await task.on(
                "state_changed",
                (snapshot) => {
                    let progress =
                        (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;

                    if (firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING)
                        setUploadProgress(progress);
                },
                (error) => {
                    console.log("Error uploading file: " + error);
                },
                () => {
                    task.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((downloadURL) => {
                        setFileUrl(downloadURL);
                    });
                }
            );
        }

        createPlan();
        setIsPlanCreated(true);
    };

    const createPlan = () => {
        let plansRef = firebase.database().ref().child("plans");
        let newPlanRef = plansRef.push();

        newPlanRef.set({
            plan_id: newPlanRef.key,
            plan_name: planName,
            created_by: currUserId,
            project_id: props.match.params.id,
            status: "active",
            category: categoryName || "uncategorized",
            file_url: fileUrl || "",
        });
    };

    const handlePlanName = (_planName) => setPlanName(_planName);

    return isPlanCreated ? (
        <Redirect to={"/project/" + props.match.params.id} />
    ) : (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Link
                to={"/project/" + props.match.params.id}
                style={styles.crossContainer}
            >
                <Image source={cross} style={styles.cross} />
            </Link>
            <View style={styles.topArea}>
                <Image source={plus} style={styles.plus} />
                <Text style={styles.title}>New Plan</Text>
                {!isPlanNameValid ? (
                    <Text style={styles.errorText}>
                        Please enter a valid name.
                    </Text>
                ) : null}
                <TextInput
                    placeholder="Plan Name"
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholderTextColor="#fff"
                    onChangeText={handlePlanName}
                />
                {uploadProgress > 0 && uploadProgress < 100 ? (
                    <Text>Upload Progress: {uploadProgress.toFixed(0)}%</Text>
                ) : null}
                {uploadProgress === 100 ? <Text>Upload Complete</Text> : null}
                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={styles.button}
                    onPress={() => {
                        getDocumentAsync().then(async (response) => {
                            try {
                                let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
                                setRef(
                                    storageRef.child(
                                        response.uri.split("/")[14]
                                    )
                                );

                                let fetchResponse = await fetch(response.uri);
                                let blob = await fetchResponse.blob();

                                setBlob(blob);
                            } catch (error) {
                                console.log(error.message);
                            }
                        });
                    }}
                >
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Upload Plan</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.bottomArea}
                onPress={() => {
                    validate();
                }}
            >
                <Text style={styles.createText}>Create</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    // -- STYLES --
});

export default NewPlan;
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you're returning a cleanup function from `useEffect`... try doing that first

Comment: I removed it because it wasn't working, but added it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `mounted` variable doesn't do anything. The only place it's checked is at the beginning of the `useEffect`, where it's definitely `true`.

While you could check it inside the `onAuthStateChanged` callback:

```
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            if (mounted && user) {
                setCurrUserId(user.uid);
            }
        });
```

It would be better to use the unsubscribe function returned by firebase:

```
useEffect(() => firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
        setCurrUserId(user.uid);
    }
}), []);
```

Or, de-sugared:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
            setCurrUserId(user.uid);
        }
    });
    return unsubscribe;
}, []);
```

It looks like you have multiple asynchronous actions that may be going on at the time that the component gets unmounted, which can't really be canceled easily. You can add a ref that indicates whether the component is currently mounted or not, and check that before calling any of the setter functions:

```
const mountedRef = useRef(true);
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
            setCurrUserId(user.uid);
        }
    });
    return () => {
        mountedRef.current = false;
        unsubscribe();
    }
}, []);
```

and then, eg, instead of

```
setBlob(blob);
```

do

```
if (mountedRef.current) {
    setBlob(blob);
};
```

and follow the same pattern wherever there's a setter that might have run asynchronously.

Comment: It's still not working for me. Do you think it could be caused by the async function ```uploadAndCreate()```?

Comment: Thank you so much. It reduced to 1 error. I also had to go to the redirected component to do the same process, worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to use the check return value from the `onAuthStateChanged` function.

```js
useEffect(() => {

  const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
      setCurrUserId(user.uid);
    }
  });

  return unsubscribe;
}, []);
```

Check other answer from CertainPerformance

Comment: yeah, sorry, forgot to update :D the other answer with the unsubscribe is on point

Comment: Updated to not reflect wrong answer, still voting for the other answer

Comment: Thank you Julian.